# python pass arguments to function separated by character

Tags: python, django, django-q

For the [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in Django, I'd like to be able to parse `AND`, `OR` queries.  Here is an example of a query to be parsed:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Poll.objects.filter(
    Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6))
)
```

This query is identical:

```
a = Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2))
b = Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6))

Poll.objects.filter(
    a | b
)
```

Is it possible to parse a query like the one below? It will obviously fail because `join` returns a string concatenated with the character `|`.  But that is the Django ORM syntax needed, and we'd like to dynamically be able to parse these queries without hard coding the `Q` arguments.

```
a = Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2))
b = Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6))

Poll.objects.filter(
    " | ".join([a,b])
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Concatenate Q objects with `|` operator? Or parse a string?

Comment: @Mikel I'm trying to concatenate Q objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to compose that programatically by repeating the or operator:

```
q = Q()
for some_date in collection_of_dates:
    q |= Q(pub_date=some_date)
Poll.objects.filter(q)
```